# when i enter the password the first time and its correct, it comes up as incorrect how do i fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.10

```
password = 'letmein'
user_input = str(input('Enter your password:\n'))
while user_input is not password:
    a = str(input('Password is wrong, Please try again:\n'))
    if a == password:
      print('Welcome Back!')
      break
    else:
      continue
```

Comment: Use != instead of is not

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `is not` to compare strings.
`else: continue` is useless at the end of a loop.
Print "Welcome" *after* the loop.
`input()` returns a string so no need to use `str()`.

```
password = 'letmein'
while user_input := input("Enter your password: ") != password:
    print("Password is wrong, Please try again:")
print('Welcome Back!')
```

See also: [Why does comparing strings using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1504717/669576)

Answer (score 0):

In the loop header you're using the `is` operator to see if two variables point to the same object, but in the if statement you're using the `==` operator to see if their *values* are the same. Since they're not the same object (you can use the [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function to check) you will enter the loop. Once inside the loop, if you do enter the same *value*, you'll get the "Welcome Back!" message.

Answer (score 0):

as others explained above,
here's a clean version of what you want to do

```
password = "letmein"
while True:
 password = input("Enter your password: ")
 if password == "letmein":
    print("Welcome Back!")
    break
 else:
    print("Password is wrong, Please try again:\n")
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

The == operator compares the values of both the operands and checks for value equality. Whereas is operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object or not. The same is the case for != and is not.

whenever we use str() method, it creates a new object of class String.
If we will use `while user_input != password:` While loop will not get executed for once.